# ACF disable / hide select option of field for multiple username

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields and I have a field called "packages" with several select options. Users can create and change packaged when the are logged in. Some options of this field should not be visible for specific users. Not user roles but user names.

This are the options and the bold one should not be visible or read-only if user is "specific user name".

- Back-up Entry
- Back-up Start
- Back-up Medium
  **- Back-up Pro**

I searched a lot and found a lot of articles and I managed to get it working to disable the whole field with this part of code:

```
function my_acf_prepare_field_wordpress( $field ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( $current_user->user_login == "Username" ) {
        if( $field['value'] ) {
            $field['disabled'] = true;
        }
    }
    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=package_or_service', 'my_acf_prepare_field_wordpress');
```

This part is disabling the whole field based on a specific username. Is there a way to only disable a specific option of this field?

**Edit**

I made this changes to get the index value of the array and unset it but no luck so far:

```
function my_acf_prepare_field_wordpress( $field ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( $current_user->user_login == "Username" ) {
        $choices = $field['choices'];
        unset($field['choices'][webhosting]);

    }
    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=package_or_service', 'my_acf_prepare_field_wordpress');
```

**Vardump**
array(6) { ["webhosting"]=> string(10) "webhosting" ["vps hosting"]=> string(11) "vps hosting" ["reseller hosting"]=> string(16) "reseller hosting" ["domeinnaam"]=> string(10) "domeinnaam" ["email"]=> string(5) "email" ["dedicated server"]=> string(16) "dedicated server" }

Comment: I don’t think ACF currently has any mechanism to make a single option disabled. You could however just remove the option completely, by removing the corresponding entry from `$field['choices']`

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. Removing would even be better then disble the option. So you are saying that I can get all the options and then remove a specific option I want to remove?

Comment: `$field['choices']` should already hold all the options as configured for that field, you can check similar discussions in their support forum, such as https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-dynamically-remove-choices-from-select-field/ They are using the `load_field` filter there instead of `prepare_field` though, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes I allready found that post, that is getting close of what I want but cant seem to figure out how to remove a specific option and then return all other options.

Comment: Find the index position where your option to remove is located in `$field['choices']`, and then use `unset($field['choices'][$index]);` …?

Comment: I coudl try that. I am only a bit confused what you mean with $index? Could you explain?

Comment: `$field['choices']` is a numerically indexed array, holding the data for the individual options. You need to find the position of the option you want to remove … the _index_ it has in that array.

Comment: Ok, I am a bit new to this and still learning. So the choices are inside an array and array always starting at 0 right? So my choice that I want to remove is 5. I made an edit in my answer but that did not do anything. Is there something I am doing wrong

Comment: I don’t think you should be using `get_field_object` here - `$field` gets already passed into this function as a parameter, it should contain the field data already. Put `var_dump($field); exit;` at the beginning of the function, and check what it actually contains.

Comment: Thanks for you answer once again. Help is much appreciated:) I once again edited my answer with to output of the vardump.

Comment: Sorry I submitted the comment to soo. So now I got my vardump of this field. The array contains everything but I see no index ID's. Is this because it are strings?

Comment: `["choices"]=> array(6) { ["webhosting"]=> string(10) "webhosting"` - okay, it appears to be an associative array, not a numerically indexed one. So `unset($field['choices']['webhosting']);` should get rid of that option. (Replace `webhosting` with the key of the option you actually want to remove.)

Comment: Wow, you made my day and I also learned something of how the array's are handled in ACF. Can become handy in the future. If I could give you the answer, I would. Maybe you can post it as answer because I really searched everywhere so maybe it can help other people out too:)